# how to calculate the max-height of a series of divs?

Tags: javascript, magento2, alpine.js

in this container, I need to calculate the heights of all divs with class `.product-name` in order to uniform all the title's heights and avoid overlaps with underlying elements. I'm using Alpine to do this, and I think the best solution is to use `x-ref`to grab the container.

cause I'm in Magento2, and there are a lot of product carousels, I need every file `item.phmtl` will be able to calculate this height based on their titles.

I've tried with `$nextTick`, but I really don't know how to circle all the x-refs to get the maximum height between all the titles.

this is the container:

```
<div class="product-name" x-data="{ titleHeight: null }"
                     x-init="$nextTick(() => { 
                     let maxHeight = 0;
                     const titleElements = $refs.title;
                     for (let i = 0; i < titleElements.length; i++) {
                         const height = titleElements[i].offsetHeight;
                         maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, height);
                     }
                     titleHeight = maxHeight;
                 })">
                    <h2 class="product-name-container font-verdana font-bold text-semi-md" x-ref="title" x-bind:style="{ height: titleHeight + 'px' }">
                        <a class="flex flex-col"
                           href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($product->getProductUrl()) ?>">

                            <span class="product-name-text block text-ash"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($productName[0]) ?></span>
                            <span class="product-name-text block text-gray-500 font-bold"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($productName[1]) ?></span>
                            <?php if(count($productName) > 2): ?>
                                <span class="product-name-text block text-ash"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($productName[2]) ?></span>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                    <?php if($showDescription): ?>
                        <div class="hidden lg:block mt-2 mb-1 items-center justify-center font-normal leading-6 text-xs text-primary text-center <?= $viewIsGrid ? '' : 'md:text-left' ?>">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $productViewModel->getShortDescriptionForProduct($product); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>
```

at the moment I'm using a for circle to loop over, but it doesn't work, all the heights are different. I'm avoiding using querySelectorAll, cause as I've said, there are lots of `.product-name`containers.

How can I achieve this result? any ideas guys? Cause I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code with this:-

```
for (let i = 0; i < titleElements.length; i++) {
     const height = titleElements[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
     maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, height);
}
```